# How to set global style on event in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have written an app in Svelte and would like to add a dark mode that anyone could activate after clicking a button. I added a Property called isDarkMode to switch the two cases. If the property is true, I want to change the background color of the body to a dark color, but the background color does not change.

```
{#if isDarkMode}
    <style>
        :global(body){
            background: #2e3440;
        }
    </style>
{/if}
```

Comment: I would probably take a different approach. If you stick with CSS (as opposed to CSS-in-JS) I would add the theme class name to the body element. So you have a regular body-style and a `body.dark-mode` style. Then you don't need conditionals littered around your application. (assuming that you are styling more than your body)

Comment: As to why it doesn't change. The style-block as far as I know isn't reative. Once compiled the CSS is extracted "out" of the template. How is `isDarkMode` defined?

Comment: Here is a demo of what I suggest https://svelte.dev/repl/ed4fef4beceb4b0eb295d1f9fdf3bd62?version=3.6.9

Comment: could you make official answer with that?

Comment: @skyboyer I posted an answer now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The style tag in Svelte isn't reactive like the other parts of a Svelte file (citation needed). So once the the file is compiled the CSS is generated (unique IDs, animations, and other good stuff).

I would take a different approach to implement a "Dark Mode". A common approach for non-'CSS-in-JS' land is to add a theme class to the `body` tag.

1. Define a default style for all of your pages and components (the "Light Mode" if you will.
2. Define overrides in typically CSS manner for when the body tag has the theme enabled.

You'll need a toggle or something else to trigger "dark mode" (e.g. time of day). In this example it is a Button component:

```
<script>
function toggle() {
    window.document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode')
}
</script>
<button on:click={toggle}>Toggle mode</button>
```

That's all there is too it. Then for your `body` and for other components you can style accordingly:

```
// App.svelte
<style>
    :global(body) {
        background-color: #f2eee2;
        color: #0084f6;
        transition: background-color 0.3s
    }
    :global(body.dark-mode) {
        background-color: #1d3040;
        color: #bfc2c7;
    }
</style>
// Button.svelte or any other component that adjusts to mode
<style>
    button {
        background-color: #f76027;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    :global(body.dark-mode) button { 
        background-color: #0084f6;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
```

Notice that only the body-part (no pun intended) is global `:global(body.dark-mode)`. If you were to put the `button` inside as well you would loose the unique ID generated by Svelte for your component and it would affect all buttons.

[Demo in REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ed4fef4beceb4b0eb295d1f9fdf3bd62?version=3.6.9)

Answer (score 10):

If you are willing to use css variables to manage your themes, you can toggle stylesheets in Svelte using the `<svelte:head>` tag :

```
<script>
    let dark = false;
    const toggleTheme = () => dark = dark === false
</script>

<svelte:head>
    {#if dark}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="change/this/path/dark-theme.css">
    {/if}
</svelte:head>

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<button on:click={toggleTheme}>
    toggle theme
</button>
```

It should make it easier to manage styling across your app, as well as reduce the total bundle size and avoid using the `:global` selector in css.

You can find the working demo here:
https://svelte.dev/repl/1a121a39eddb4b3682a7701a35ac6824?version=3.6.9

Comment: The example doesn't seem to work anymore. It errors (in the console) with a 404 when trying to load the `dark-theme.css` after clicking the toggle button.

Comment: Are you sure the path to the CSS file is the right one? A 404 error means it most likely work but the file isn't found.

Comment: You're right, the example simply seem to miss any additional css files (which may not even be possible on the Svelte REPL). I just had a different expectation of "working demo" ;).

Comment: Fair enough. The demo was working at the time, but it has been 4years so the repl might be different now.

Answer (score 1):

For SvelteKit, we can set global style using :global(selector) modifier. For example:

```css
<style>
    :global(body) {
        /* this will apply to <body> */
        margin: 0;
    }

    div :global(strong) {
        /* this will apply to all <strong> elements, in any
             component, that are inside <div> elements belonging
             to this component */
        color: goldenrod;
    }

    p:global(.red) {
        /* this will apply to all <p> elements belonging to this 
             component with a class of red, even if class="red" does
             not initially appear in the markup, and is instead 
             added at runtime. This is useful when the class 
             of the element is dynamically applied, for instance 
             when updating the element's classList property directly. */
    }
</style>
```

Ref: [SvelteKit Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-style)